# How to get array filters to work for Mongoose? Nodejs, Mongoose, pug

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, pug

**Update: Not working because Mongoose does support array filters, can someone figure out how to achieve this using something Mongoose does support, like $project or $group or anything?

What I want to happen:
To set every "used" field in the "records" array to **true** if it is already set to false.

My collection looks like this:

```
{room: 209, 
 school: "Lime Vernon HS", 
 records:[
       {date:'3/24/2018',
        lesson:'Treble Clef', 
        game:'Trebleball', 
        used:false,
        cancel:false
       }, 
       {
         date:'3/24/2018', 
         lesson:'Treble Clef', 
         game:'Trebleball', 
         used:false, 
         cancel:false
       }, 
       {
         date:'3/24/2018', 
         lesson:'', game:'', 
         used:true, 
         cancel:true
       }, 
       {
         date:'3/24/2018', 
         lesson:'Treble Clef', 
         game:'Trebleball', 
         used:false, 
         cancel:false
      }]
```

Here is the code I used:

```
Hook.updateMany({ room:209}, { $set: { "records.$[elem].used" : true } },
{ arrayFilters: [ { "elem.used": false } ] }, function(err){

    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    else{
        return res.redirect("/home")
    }

})
```

The result: Nothing happened, my collection still looks exactly the same as if I had done nothing at all.

The result I wanted ("used" field to be set to true):

```
{room: 209, 
 school: "Lime Vernon HS", 
 records:[
       {date:'3/24/2018',
        lesson:'Treble Clef', 
        game:'Trebleball', 
        used: true,
        cancel:false
       }, 
       {
         date:'3/24/2018', 
         lesson:'Treble Clef', 
         game:'Trebleball', 
         used: true, 
         cancel:false
       }, 
       {
         date:'3/24/2018', 
         lesson:'', game:'', 
         used:true, 
         cancel:true
       }, 
       {
         date:'3/24/2018', 
         lesson:'Treble Clef', 
         game:'Trebleball', 
         used: true, 
         cancel:false
      }]
```

This is my schema :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var uniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator');

var HookSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
room:{
    type:Number,
    required:true
},
classPoints:{
    type:Number,
    default:0
},
uanns: [Announcement], 
newHires: [Workers],
firstlights:[Award],
octlights:[Award],
novlights:[Award],
declights:[Award],
janlights:[Award],
feblights:[Award],
marlights:[Award],
aprlights:[Award],
maylights:[Award],
junlights:[Award],
eon:[AwardB],
milestone:[AwardB],
legend:[AwardB],
eonNominees:[Nominee],
reservedAvatars:[Reserved],
records:[Record]
```

});

Answer (score 0):

```
    Hook.find({room:209}).arrayFilters( [ { "elem.used": false } ] )
   .updateMany( { $set: { "records.$[elem].used" : true } } );
```

Try with this please,firstly filter:)

Comment: No that didn't work either. But thank you for trying.

Comment: What is used type in your schema?

Comment: I added my schema code at the bottom of the post for you. Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: i need type of used like:String or Array ?

Comment: the type is Boolean